# Navigation property is null after EF 5.x to EF 6.x upgrade, except when breakpoint is set

Tags: entity-framework

My context and entities are generated with the "EF 6.x DbContext Generator".  I'm working with Visual Studio 2012, and installed the [Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762) after upgrading from EF 5.x.  I followed [the upgrade guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx), including deleting the existing .tt files and re-creating.

After upgrading, a piece of my code now throws an exception due to a null navigation property that I try to access.  This code previously worked fine under the earlier version of EF.  The piece of code looks like:

```
var messageSubject = "Status of " + trade.TradeType.TradeTypeDescription +
                     " (" + trade.TradeNumber + ") has changed - " +
                     trade.TradeStatus.TradeStatusDescription;
```

The bit that's throwing the exception is `trade.TradeStatus.TradeStatusDescription`, since TradeStatus is strangely null.  trade.TradeType is not null, despite being a near identical navigation property.  Both are simple reference tables, allowing me to map a code to a description.

Even more strangely, if I set a breakpoint before the offending line, and then step over the code, the navigation property is not null, and no null reference exception occurs.  Some delay or race condition?

Also, if I eager load the navigation property prior to accessing it, TradeStatus is not null and the code works fine:

```
var trade = _partiesRepository.Trades.Include("TradeStatus").First(x => x.TradeNumber == tradeViewModel.Trade.TradeNumber);
```

Lazy Loading Enabled is set to true in my edmx file.  I can't understand why all of a sudden TradeStatus is now null unless I explicitly eager load it.  Why is lazy loading suddenly not working for this one navigation property?

Comment: I know this is some time since you asked this question but we have a similar problem in current project. After developing for almost a year now some EF Entities have navigation properties NULL suddenly for no reason.